# "onclick" button in html form not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="button" 
               value="Register" 
               onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                               this.form.username,
                               this.form.email,
                               this.form.password,
                               this.form.confirmpwd);" />
```

When i try to click on that its like no reaction. Just trying to add informations from form, to my php script.

Comment: Have you check in browser debug mode if the `regformhash` function is called?

Comment: how to do that? im using Chrome, and checked this form on Safari and Firefox.

Comment: any errors in the dev console ?

Comment: Learn to use the Chrome developer tools.  They'll make your life much easier: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Press F12 and go to the Sources tab. Look for your code page and use breakpoints where you have the function defined.

Comment: In some cases there is an extracheck assoiciated when there is return keyword used ? have you tried it without return ?

Comment: Check whether the function is returning `false`

Comment: Not working without return.

Comment: in console i have a wrote in red collor all js scripts which im using to this form. They giving no response.. its strange, because i send them to good location.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle with html and js and post link here.

Comment: Ok... i made an error in syntax. Gave bad source of one of js files. Sorry, and thank you

Comment: Do you understand what `this` is when `regformhash` is called?

Answer (score 1):

The following is working snippet with your example for username field, add your other input fields and pass those to function.

```js
function regformhash(form, username){
            alert("username:  "+username);

           }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value= "myUserName" name ="username"/>
  <input type="button" value="Register" onclick=" regformhash(this.form,this.form.username.value);"/> 
          
</form>
```